# Selector is expected to be initialized with a function

Tags: testing, ecmascript-6, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I successfully selected a bunch of page elements and now I'm passing all these elements to separate page models and helper functions.

On the latter, I created a helper function class as follows:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

export default class Helpers {
  selectPageElement (elementName) {
    const elementTitle = Selector ('div').child('h2');

    const numberOfElements = elementTitle.count;

    if (numberOfElements) {
      for (let i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        if (elementTitle.nth(i) === 'aname') {
          return elementTitle.nth(i);
        }
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Then on my test file I'm calling that method as follows:

```
import { ClientFunction, Selector } from 'testcafe';
import Helpers from './helpers';

...
const helpers = new Helpers();

test('Test name', async t => {
  ...
  await t
    .click(helpers.selectPageElement('Element Name'));
});
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Action "selector" argument error:

Selector is expected to be initialized with a function, CSS selector string, 
another Selector, node snapshot or a Promise returned by a Selector,
but undefined was passed.
```

I'm fairly new to ES6, so I believe it's something with the way I'm calling the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution could be:

```
export default class Helpers {
  selectPageElement (elementName) {
    return Selector('div > h2')
      .withText(elementName);
  }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I want to add is that this original code
`const numberOfElements = elementTitle.count;`
will probably work incorrectly, since the `await` keyword is missing. Please refer to this section https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/.